# How to find distance matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

I am using `pdist2(x(i), y(j), 'euclidean')` formula to find euclidean distance between x and y instead of the manual method

```
sqrt((x(i)-y(i))^2).
```

And to find co relation coefficient I am using `corrcoeff( x(i), y(j))` . Is this the correct way to find correlation coefficient and euclidean distance between x and y matrix? 
I get different answers when I use formula and manual method.

Comment: It looks correct, but probably `pdist2(x,y,'euclidean')` makes more sense than `pdist2(x(i),y(j),'euclidean')` does. Show your code so that we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation between the two matrices can be calculated as:

```
r = corr2(x,y)
```

Now, if you are after the element-wise distance, how about:

```
dist=gsqrt((x-y).^2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not correct.

I suppose `x` and `y` are matrixes, so you are using `pdist2` to compute the distance between the observation *i* (from `x(i)`) and *j* (from `y(j)`). In the case of the manual method you are using the `i` index in both of them. **Maybe the differences are due to the incorrect use of the indexes *i* and *j***. Show us your code so we can confirm it.

By the way, as @Luis pointed out, it is better to use `pdist2` to compute all the distances at the same time (it is much faster). So, if you have two matrixes x and y, use: `pdist2(x,y)`.

The same for the correlation.